# update entrie in table PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Novice with PHP, I'm trying to update users table but, I don't understand why but it's working with solution #1 and not with solution #2, someone can help me ?

```
<?php 
/* SOLUTION #2 */
/*function updateUser(PDO $database, string $key, string $entrie) : void {
        $value = htmlentities($_POST[$key]);

        $req = $database->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET '.$entrie.'=:value WHERE username=:user');
        $req->execute([
            "user" => $_SESSION['username'],
            "value" => $value
        ]);

        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;

        header('Location: ./profile.php');
}


if (!empty($_POST['newname']))
    updateUser($db, 'newname', 'username');*/

/* SOLUTION #1 */
if (!empty($_POST['newname'])){
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['newname']);
    $req = $db->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET username=:newuser WHERE username=:user');
    $req->execute([
        "user" => $_SESSION['username'],
        "newuser" => $name
    ]);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
    header('Location: ./profile.php');
}
```

?>

Comment: What is an error with solution #2?

Comment: Hey, no changes appears in database

Comment: Are you sure $_SESSION['username'] contains the correct data?

Comment: the `htmlentities()` is not required.